# React Semantic UI - position icon to the left of text in Menu Item

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Using React Semantic UI the default look is this

[image: React Semantic UI default look for Menu-items with an icon]

This is the code (from the website) which produces that component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Icon, Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class MenuExampleCompactVertical extends Component {
  state = {}

  handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name })

  render() {
    const { activeItem } = this.state

    return (
      <Menu compact icon='labeled' vertical inverted>
        <Menu.Item name='gamepad' active={activeItem === 'gamepad'} onClick={this.handleItemClick}>
          <Icon name='gamepad' />
          Games
        </Menu.Item>

        <Menu.Item
          name='video camera'
          active={activeItem === 'video camera'}
          onClick={this.handleItemClick}
        >
          <Icon name='video camera' />
          Channels
        </Menu.Item>

        <Menu.Item
          name='video play'
          active={activeItem === 'video play'}
          onClick={this.handleItemClick}
        >
          <Icon name='video play' />
          Videos
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    )
  }
}
```

I'd like to position the icons left of the text like this

[image: Icons positioned left of text]

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I added the code from the website which produces the default menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like I managed to answer my own question.  It's not great, but it looks like a little css does the trick.

Just float the icon left

```
i {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 12px !important;
}
```

the menu item itself just becomes an `a` element

```
a {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

EDIT:

This is what I actually ended up using, if anyone wants to know.  The CSS rules make it a little complicated to get your own rules in based on precedence.

```
/******     Sidebar     ******/

.ui.icon.menu .item {
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-right: 500px;
    text-align: justify;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.ui.vertical.menu .item::before {
    height: 0px;
}

.ui.labeled.icon.menu .item > .icon:not(.dropdown) {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 12px !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't before but in December 2019, you can give them your own custom class names and put properties that you'd like to override. i.e.: `<Menu.Item className="app__menu-item" name="spam" ... </Menu.Item>` and in the css file `.app__menu-item {  text-align: left; }`

Comment: For me, `<Menu.Item className="app__menu-item" name="spam" ... </Menu.Item>` with `.app__menu-item {  text-align: left; }` will produce styling that is not as high a priority as `.ui.icon.menu .item`. As a result, css tyle has to be for `.ui.icon.menu.item` and you have to use the `!important` override.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get CSS overrides to work, semantic always won that fight!

I did it by putting my Icon component inside an Icon.Group

```
...
          <Menu.Item name='about'>
            <Icon.Group size='large'>
              <Icon name='question circle' />
            </Icon.Group>
            About
          </Menu.Item>
...
```

I used this page for inspiration:
https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/icon/#groups-twitter-group

Answer (score 0):

A plain old `<span>` should do the trick here.

```
<Menu.Item name='create'>
  <span>
    <Icon name='pen square' />
    Create
  </span>
</Menu.Item>
```

Another approach that keeps things centered and is a little easier to work with:

```
<div style={{ display: "inline-flex" }}>
  <Icon size='large' name='pen square' />
  <p style={{ margin: "auto" }}>Create</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Just use a [list](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/list.html#inverted) this looks nearly as you like it too